# What are joint angles of Kinova Jaco in home position?

Tags: joint, precise-positioning

I want to work with Kinova Jaco with spherical wrist in CoppeliaSim, because currently I do not have access to a physical manipulator. The model there is in reset configuration (arm fully extended and points up), but I want it to be in home configuration.
Does anyone know what are values of joint positions for Kinova Jaco with spherical wrist in home configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the quarantine going less strict I finally have an access to a physical Jaco arm.
If someone else will need this info, here are the joint positions of Jaco arm in the home state:
$$
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{home}=\begin{bmatrix}
4.8055, 2.9211, 0.9989, 4.2076, 1.4420, 1.3220
\end{bmatrix}rad
$$
And these are joint positions in retracted state.
$$
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{ret}=\begin{pmatrix}
4.7143, 2.6191, 0.4693, 4.6728, 0.0916, 1.7412
\end{pmatrix}rad
$$
Finally, these are joint positions in retracted state just after you turn on the Jaco and before you do any operation:
$$
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{ret\_off}=\begin{pmatrix}
4.7246, 2.6108, 0.3681, 4.6694, 0.0905, 1.7441
\end{pmatrix}rad
$$